# Getting the arguments passed to vlc

Tags: c#, vlc

I have a C# application.

I am using the excellent VLC wrapper created by Roman Ginzburg which I found at CodeProject [nvlc](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/109639/nVLC)

I have a RTSP camera connected to my local network.  It is on a static IP address of 192.168.100.100.

If I use the DLLs of the VLC project of the 32bit version it works.

If I use the DLLs of the VLC project of the 64bit version it does not work.

But, if I actually just use the VLC 64 bit application without going through my C# app it works.

So, I assume it must be down to the arguments I am passing to libvlc.dll.

I have tried adding and removing all the arguments I know that work successfully with the 32 bit version but all I get are black frames/images.

I went back to the VLC application to see if I could find anywhere the arguments that are used.

I cannot seem to find anything.

I did try to look at the logging files produced but the log file is never created.  I have used verbose up to 4 but still the log file is not created.

I have even tried using Fiddler to see if I could 'trap' the arguments but it just looks at HTTP/HTTPS streams.

These are the arguments I use with the 32 bit that works:

```
        string[] args = new string[] 
         {
            "-I", 
            "dummy",  
            "--ignore-config", 
            "--no-osd",
            "--disable-screensaver",
            "--ffmpeg-hw",
            "--live-caching=100 ",
            "--rtsp-caching=100",
            "--realrtsp-caching=100",
            "--network-caching=0",

            "--skip-frames",
            "--drop-late-frames",
            "--plugin-path=./plugins" 
         };
```

It looks like I may have to go back to the 32 bit version.

Not unless anyone could suggest anything to a poor Windows developer trying to use VLC in their application?

Comment: How are you building your C# application? Go check ***"Project properties"-->Tab "Build"*** and tell us what architecture you are targeting

Comment: HI, will do. 1 sec :)

Comment: It was set at 'Any CPU'. I just tried to run it under 'x64' but still have the same issue

Comment: Your application has to target the same architecture like all your references. If you reference 32-bit assembly your application has to be build in 32-bit or Any CPU mode. When you reference 64-bit you should switch it to x64. If this does not fix your problem I am out of ideas.

Comment: @RononDex. Yes, I had done that and still no joy. But thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and this was my solution:

```
media.AddOptions(new[] { ":network-caching=300" });
```

I think the important part is that it requires the ":" at the beginning of the Option.

This is the full code I'm using to open the stream:

```
IMediaPlayerFactory factory = new MediaPlayerFactory();
var media = factory.CreateMedia<IMedia>(string.Format(@"rtsp://{0}:5658", hostTxt.Text));
media.AddOptions(new[] { string.Format(":network-caching={0}", networkCaching) });
VideoStreamingPlayer = factory.CreatePlayer<IVideoPlayer>();
VideoStreamingPlayer.WindowHandle = video.Handle;
VideoStreamingPlayer.Open(media);
VideoStreamingPlayer.Events.MediaEnded += VideoStreamingPlayer_MediaEnded;
VideoStreamingPlayer.Play();
```